# Send shipping address into Authorize.net

Tags: php, curl, authorize.net

I have implemented the Authorize.net payment method in my web site. I have sent the billing info and payment into to the autorize.net. But I want to send the shipping information too. I am using the following code

```
"x_first_name"   => $firstname,
"x_last_name"   => $lastname,
"x_address"    => $bill_address,
"x_city"    => $bill_city,
"x_state"    => $bill_state,
"x_zip"     => $bill_zip,
"x_country"     => $bill_country,
"x_phone"    => $phone,
```

Using curl to send the data.

Does any one know how to send the shipping info?

Thanks in advance

Comment: which API are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's clearly documented in Authorize.net's online docs.

Direct link to the shipping info data: http://developer.authorize.net/guides/AIM/Transaction_Data_Requirements/Shipping_Information.htm

Basically:

```
x_ship_to_first_name  
x_ship_to_last_name
x_ship_to_company
x_ship_to_address
x_ship_to_city
x_ship_to_state
x_ship_to_zip
x_ship_to_country
```

And overall documentation: http://developer.authorize.net/guides/AIM/